# android: bring current activity to front via notification

Tags: android

i know there are numerous questions about this, but they didn't help me.
At some Point my app creates a notification and i want it to bring the current app to the front without creating a new one.

My Code(inside MainActivty):

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(this,MainActivity.class);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0, intent, 0);
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .setContentTitle("Titel")
            .setContentText("Text")
            .addAction(new NotificationCompat.Action(R.mipmap.ic_launcher, "Testtitel",
                    pendingIntent));
    NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    manager.notify(0,builder.build());
```

the notfication is shown correctly but clicking on it has no effect. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: When ever a notification is received you can transfer the page to an activity using Intents

Comment: i got it working with `.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);` instead of `addAction`

Answer (score 0):

I am using notification in my application and if a particular notification is received I am directly opening my activity like below

```
     if (notification_type.equalsIgnoreCase("3")) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Notification: " + "Before Meeting");

                    PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
                    PowerManager.WakeLock wakeLock = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK
                            | PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP
                            | PowerManager.ON_AFTER_RELEASE, "MyWakeLock");
                    wakeLock.acquire();
                    KeyguardManager km = (KeyguardManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.KEYGUARD_SERVICE);
                    final KeyguardManager.KeyguardLock kl = km.newKeyguardLock("MyKeyguardLock");
                    kl.disableKeyguard();

                        Intent intentToMain = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
                        intentToMain.putExtra("destroy", "destroy");
                        intentToMain.addFlags(intentToMain.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                        startActivity(intentToMain);

                }
```